# Table tests for multi-return value function

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I'm cutting my teeth on Go and after digging into [table driven tests](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests) I ran into the following problem:

I have a function that returns multiple values

```
// Halves an integer and and returns true if it was even or false if it was odd.
func half(n int) (int, bool) {
    h := n / 2
    e := n%2 == 0
    return h, e
}
```

I know that for `half(1)` the return value should be `0, false` and for `half(2)` it should match `1, true`, but I can't seem to figure out how to put this on a table.

How would one go to have something that resembles the following?

```
var halfTests = []struct {
    in  int
    out string
}{
    {1, <0, false>},
    {3, <1, true>},
}
```

Is there any other, more idiomatic way of doing this?

For reference, here's a test for something that resembles a FizzBuzz function, using tables:

```
var fizzbuzzTests = []struct {
    in  int
    out string
}{
    {1, "1"},
    {3, "Fizz"},
    {5, "Buzz"},
    {75, "FizzBuzz"},
}

func TestFizzBuzz(t *testing.T) {
    for _, tt := range fizzbuzzTests {
        s := FizzBuzz(tt.in)
        if s != tt.out {
            t.Errorf("Fizzbuzz(%d) => %s, want %s", tt.in, s, tt.out)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add another field to your struct that holds the second return value. Example:

```
var halfTests = []struct {
    in   int
    out1 int
    out2 bool
}{
    {1, 0, false},
    {3, 1, true},
}
```

Your testing function would look like the following:

```
func TestHalf(t *testing.T) {
    for _, tt := range halfTests {
        s, t := half(tt.in)
        if s != tt.out1 || t != tt.out2 {
            t.Errorf("half(%d) => %d, %v, want %d, %v", tt.in, s, t, tt.out1, tt.out2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited the question with proper formatted suggestion.